# Retrieve String itemID with mahout from PHP Server

Tags: php, mahout, mahout-recommender

I'm trying to use a recommender with mahout.
Mahout don't accept string itemid so I've used this to make it possible :
https://github.com/KlwntSingh/CustomFileModelMahout

But now I don't know how I'm supposed to get the real string id from my PHP server?
Because when I get all the data, I get results like that :

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("5617bff2e4b07732915e7023"),
    source: -7329169032418500000,
    cible: -4819202982826100000,
    type: "ar",
    hit: 1,
    projet: "cdvaldoisedev",
    dateImport: ISODate("2015-10-09T13:24:02.807Z")
}
```

So how can I get my string using the source/cible?